# How to find where the magnitude of the gradient of a function is maximized?

Tags: functions, symmetry, gradient-flows

How to  find where the magnitude of the gradient of    ${{e}^{-({{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}})}}$ maximizes?
I managed to calculate the magnitude - $2{{e}^{-({{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}})}}\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}}$

Comment: Maybe you mean the norm? Please take some care in formulating your questions in English. Calculate the norm and then you do the usual maximum finding methods of calculus.

Answer (score 2):

The magnitude of the gradient just depends on the distance from the origin $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

The function $f:[0,+\infty]\to[0,+\infty]$ defined by:
$$ f(\rho) = 2\rho\, e^{-\rho^2} $$
attains its maximum when $f'=0$. Since:
$$ f'(\rho) = 2(1-2\rho^2)e^{-\rho^2} $$
the maximum is attained for $\rho=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$:
$$ f(\rho)\leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{e}}.$$